# I cant seem to build this simple regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hello i want to create a regex expression that recognizes a specific pattern (Gendering strings inside article titles). However i  am unable to come up with a solution although it should be fairly simple.

I want to recognize one of the letters `m w t` followed by the character `|` and then again the letters `m w t`.
I want the pattern to match an infinite amount of variations between those attributes.

So example patterns that **should** match are:

```
m|w

m|w|m

m|w|t|m|m

m|w..................................|t
```

The patterns that should **NOT** match for example are:

```
t

m|

|w|

m|w|
```

The regex i have come up with so far is `((\|)?(m|w|t){1}[ ]*(\|))+` but of course this wont suit my needs. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: General FYI: You never need to write `{1}` in a regexp. Everything matches exactly once unless it's quantified.

Comment: Why do you have `[ ]*`? You never said that whitespace is allowed.

Comment: Sorry... well sometimes there might be white space between it.... i thought id figure out those part myself if i got the general idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a repeating group 1+ times

```
^[mwt](?:\|[mwt])+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[mwt]` match one of `m` `w` `t`
- `(?:\|[mwt])+` Repeat 1+ times matching `|` and again one of `m` `w` `t`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/21SaqT/1)

---

Without the anchors, you can start the match with a word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial match, and assert a whitespace boundary to the right at the end of the pattern `(?!\S)`

If you want to use multiple delimiters, you can use a character class `[|\/]` and you only have to escape the forward slash if the pattern delimiters are also `/`

```
\b[mwt] *(?:[|\/] *[mwt])+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDvjc6/1)

Comment: There is a problem with this regex though. The pattern must stand completely for itself. I want it to be matched within a sentence.... I want it to match 1 time for example inside "Hello this is a title for m|w|t "

Comment: @MajesticOl Like this? `\b[mwt](?:\|[mwt])+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/JhuhIX/1

Comment: Fantastic ! I altered it a slight bit so it also understands slashes and white spaces between the letter separators:   `\b[mwt][ ]*(?:(\||\/)[ ]*[mwt])+(?!\S)`

Comment: @MajesticOl In that case, you could shorted the pattern to `\b[mwt] *(?:[|\/] *[mwt])+(?!\S)` See https://regex101.com/r/NDvjc6/1

Comment: @MajesticOl I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Hmm why doesnt this match with the regex ? "Diätassistent (t|m|w)"

Comment: @MajesticOl That depends on how specific you want to make the pattern. This would match it `\b[mwt] *(?:[|\/] *[mwt])+\b` but note that there is no `d` in the character class. This would match the whole part, and will exclude matching either `/` or `|` at the end `\b[mwtd] *(?:[|\/] *[mwtd])+(?![|\/])` https://regex101.com/r/x6iq7H/1

Comment: Damn... you are a regex god. I will study whats going on there in detail. This pattern is it `\b[mwtd] *(?:[|\/] *[mwtd])+(?![|\/])`

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want this regex: `[mwt](\|[mwt])+`. One of the letters, followed by one or more `|`-`letter` pairs.

Comment: This would also work and i learned something from it. There would still be a match within a m|t| so i will use the above answere. Thanks again for the help man !